# Can I fetch the result of a SELECT query iteratively using LIMIT and OFFSET?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am implementing a FUSE file system that uses a sqlite3 database for its backend. I do not plan to ever change the database backend as my file system uses sqlite3 as a file format. One of the functions a file system must implement is `readdir` function. This function allows the process to iteratively read the contents of a directory by repeatedly calling it and getting the next few directory entries (as many as the buffer can hold). The directory entries are returned may be returned in any order. I want to implement this operation with the following query:

```
SELECT fileno, name FROM dirents WHERE dirno = ? LIMIT -1 OFFSET ?;
```

where `dirno` is the directory I'm reading from and `OFFSET ?` is the number of entries I've already returned. I want to read as many rows as I can fit into the buffer (I cannot predict the count as these are variable-length records depending on the length of the file name) and then reset the query.

Due to the stateless nature of FUSE,  keeping open a query and returning the next few rows until the directory has ended is not an option as I cannot reliably detect if the process closes the directory prematurely.

The `dirents` table has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE dirents (
    dirno INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES inodes(inum),
    fileno INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES inodes(inum),
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dirno, name)
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

### Question

In theory, a `SELECT` statement yields rows in no defined order. In practice, can I assume that when I execute the same prepared `SELECT` statement multiple times with successively larger `OFFSET` values, I get the same results as if I read all the data in a single query, i.e. the row order is the same unspecified order each time? An assumption that currently holds is that the database is not modified between queries.

Can I assume that the row order stays reasonably similar when a different query modifies the `dirents` table inbetween? Some glitches (e.g. directory entries appearing twice) will of course be observable by the program, but for usability (the main user of `readdir` is the `ls` command) it is highly useful if the directory listing is usually mostly correct.

If I cannot make these assumptions, what is a better way to reach the desired result?

I know that I could throw in an `ORDER BY` clause to make the row order well-defined, but I fear that this might have a strong impact on performance, especially when reading small chunks of a large directory—the directory has to be sorted every time a chunk is read.

Comment: Just add an `order by` to the query, so the results are stable.  And why are you creating it without a `rowid`?  That would be an obvious method for fetching the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Have a look at the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm creating the table without a rowid so that `(dirno, name)` is a clustered index. The most common query in that table is `SELECT fileno FROM dirents WHERE dirno = ? AND name = ?;`.

Comment: No, you cannot assume that queries without an `ORDER BY` clause have any particular ordering. But ordering by a set of columns corresponding to an index should not be that expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right solution to this problem is to use `order by`.  If you are concerned about the performance of the order by, then use an index on the column used for the `order by`.

The simplest approach, in my opinion, would be to remove the `without rowid` option on the table creation.  Then you can just access the table as:

```
SELECT fileno, name
FROM dirents
WHERE dirno = ?
ORDER BY rowid
LIMIT -1 OFFSET ?;
```

I realize this adds additional bytes to each row, but it is for a good purpose -- making sure that your queries are correct.

Actually, the best index for this table would be on `dirno, rowid, fileno, name`.  Given the `where` clause, you are doing a full table scan anyway, unless you have an index.

Comment: `WITHOUT ROWID` tables are required to have a primary key, and thus an index, so one could just order by the primary keys.

Comment: would it be just as good if I kept the `WITHOUT ROWID` table (for the clustered index) and ordered by `dirno, name`?

Comment: @FUZxxl . . . Absolutely.

Comment: For future readers: It appears that if you order by primary key (or by the first few columns of the primary key), the `ORDER BY` clause is free in that no difference to the `ORDER BY` less query can be observed in the bytecode shown by `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

If I add an `ORDER BY name` clause to the `SELECT` query, sqlite3 generates almost identical (except for a stray `Noop`) bytecode for the query but a row order is guaranteed:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN SELECT fileno, name FROM dirents WHERE dirno = ? LIMIT -1 OFFSET ?;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     21    0                    00               
1     Integer        -1    1     0                    00               
2     Variable       2     2     0                    00               
3     MustBeInt      2     0     0                    00               
4     SetIfNotPos    2     2     0                    00               
5     Add            1     2     3                    00               
6     SetIfNotPos    1     3     -1                   00               
7     OpenRead       1     3     0     k(2,nil,nil)   02               
8     Variable       1     4     0                    00               
9     IsNull         4     19    0                    00               
10    Affinity       4     1     0     D              00               
11    SeekGE         1     19    4     1              00               
12      IdxGT          1     19    4     1              00               
13      IfPos          2     18    1                    00               
14      Column         1     2     5                    00               
15      Column         1     1     6                    00               
16      ResultRow      5     2     0                    00               
17      DecrJumpZero   1     19    0                    00               
18    Next           1     12    0                    00               
19    Close          1     0     0                    00               
20    Halt           0     0     0                    00               
21    Transaction    0     0     3     0              01               
22    TableLock      0     3     0     dirents        00               
23    Goto           0     1     0                    00               
sqlite> EXPLAIN SELECT fileno, name FROM dirents WHERE dirno = ? ORDER BY name LIMIT -1 OFFSET ?;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     22    0                    00               
1     Noop           0     0     0                    00               
2     Integer        -1    1     0                    00               
3     Variable       2     2     0                    00               
4     MustBeInt      2     0     0                    00               
5     SetIfNotPos    2     2     0                    00               
6     Add            1     2     3                    00               
7     SetIfNotPos    1     3     -1                   00               
8     OpenRead       2     3     0     k(2,nil,nil)   02               
9     Variable       1     4     0                    00               
10    IsNull         4     20    0                    00               
11    Affinity       4     1     0     D              00               
12    SeekGE         2     20    4     1              00               
13      IdxGT          2     20    4     1              00               
14      IfPos          2     19    1                    00               
15      Column         2     2     5                    00               
16      Column         2     1     6                    00               
17      ResultRow      5     2     0                    00               
18      DecrJumpZero   1     20    0                    00               
19    Next           2     13    0                    00               
20    Close          2     0     0                    00               
21    Halt           0     0     0                    00               
22    Transaction    0     0     3     0              01               
23    TableLock      0     3     0     dirents        00               
24    Goto           0     1     0                    00
```

So I guess I'm going for that `ORDER BY name` clause.